# Problem running “Central Administration” website after windows update at Windows 2003 Server Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I was have WSS 2.0 and then I upgraded to WSS 3.0 and the old instalation database was SQL 2000, now I have another SQL Server instance called:server_name\MICROSOFT##SSEE .

After upgrade every thing works fine and our team started to use the portal and we sent lot of documents and make lot of activities on it. The problem started after installing Windows updates the website suddenly stopped and giving me an error

> "Cannot connect to the configuration database"

If I tried to open SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard it is gives me a strange error says: "An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown. Additional exception information: SharePoint Products and Technologies cannot be configured. The current installation mode does not support SKU to SKU upgrades because there exists an older version of Windows SharePoint Services that must be upgraded first "

At this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114398/iis-error-cannot-connect-to-the-configuration-database/249494#249494 the guy of the second answer have the same problem and he suggested a solution but I don't understand well. I tried as he suggested to make the identity of the app pool of the SharePoint web site as "IWAM_server_name " after that the error changed as he said and I web site give me "Server Application Unavailable " and when checked the Event Viewer at the server I found that ASP.NET 2.0 give this exception: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied ." and I don't know how to solve this problem.

I'm really want to make my web site working because our team really need these documents and its stuff.

I hope I will find some one to help me.

Comment: Duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/41028/problem-running-central-administration-website-after-windows-update-at-windows

Comment: I merged the questions in order to bring your answer on the "non community wiki" question, Diago.

Comment: Someone with the POWER should go back to the original SO question and make a link to this version of the SF question  ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131312/ ), currently the auto generated link is going to 41028

Comment: looks like all the moving, merging and repointing has mangled these links all up.

Comment: I added it here because of the comment made by someone on stackoverflow !

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing WSS 2.0 and 3.0 completely and then reinstalling and creating a new Administration database and website.

Re-provision the old site with a new site collection and connect to the existing database, which will recreate the site completely as all the information is available in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade from WSs 2.0 to WSS 3.0, the upgrade should retain the same data base system - in your case SQL Server 2K.

it seems like the upgrade has "server_name\MICROSOFT##SSEE " with either Windows Internal Database or SQL Server 2005 Express.

This is probably causing issues because your SQL Server 2K WSS databases are still there alongside the WSS 3.0 databases.

I wonder if your sql 2000 install wasn't fully updated before the install (which WSS.30 can't use, then after windows update, got patched up to where it can use it and is somehow trying to use the old upgraded database.

More details about the upgrade would be helpful.  I would not remove both until you have ensured sql 2000 is fully patched then re-upgrade.

Comment: So, I have to update my SQL Server 2000 with last updates, then reinstall WSS 3.0 again ?

Or remove the entire WSS I have 2.0 and 3.0 and then start a new installation, in this case I don't know how to re-use my old web site !!!.

If this operation is complex, can I have import the database to a new fresh installed SharePoint server. It is installed after installing windows, it have SQL Server 2005 Ent.